# What is silverlight still missing?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Silverlight vs WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010452/silverlight-vs-wpf)

What is silverlight still missing when compared with WPF?

Comment: More importantly...a framework is only missing what you plan to use. IF you don't plan to use it, then missing something from a differing framework doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Are you joking? I mean, IN DETAIL that's a lot too much.
For a very high (abstract) level see:
http://www.dotnetspider.com/Silverlight-Tutorial-296.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have some requests for features for Silverlight you can vote for them at [UserVoice](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions).