# Why silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Why silver light is introduced even WPF is already exist in .net?? What we can achieve with silver light where we can't with WPF??

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944608/wpf-vs-silverlight

Comment: To oversimplify silverlight is a stripped down runtime environment for rich internet applications - whereas WPF targets the rich desktop client space, with all the bells-n-whistles. Google has a lot of stuff on this topic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight needs a much smaller .net runtime to run. WPF needs full .net runtime installed in your machine. From a web application it is easy for Silverlight to penetrate a huge percentage of userbase. Also Silverligt supports Windows and Mac out of box and some limited support for Linux through Moonlight.

Answer (score 2):

We can run it on MacOS, and in some cases on linux (moonlight project)