# Which to use - WPF or Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, desktop-application

I want to create a desktop like app, but I'm kind of confused as to which technology to use. It seems Silverlight functions like a desktop app. Which technology is better suited and has is more future proof?

Comment: Nothing is future proof sadly. The only guarantee is change itself.

Comment: And AFAIK silverlight has been relegated to WP7 (windows phone 7) only now is it not?

Comment: @Matt: No, not at all.  SL is getting a lot of love on the desktop for OOB support, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop apps should be built with WPF. Silverlight has a lot of security restrictions which doesn't make life easier.

Answer (score 2):

WPF is the framework to go with if you are building a desktop application. Silverlight is more of a web application framework. It all depends on where and how the application is being used.

[This Question compares the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944608/wpf-vs-silverlight).

Comment: This is quite out of date information (2009).  There's a reason Microsoft has been pushing Silverlight out of browser for most desktop development - SL 4 made great strides to help on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

> Which technology is better suited and has is more future proof?

This depends a LOT on the purpose and goals of your desktop application.

If your application needs to interop with the system in a "non-standard" way, or provide other types of 3rd party interop, WPF will be a superior solution (at least until SL 5's P/Invoke support).

However, if your application is a LOB application, Silverlight (running OOB) has many advantages - especially if you want to take advantage of things like RIA Services (which hasn't been ported to WPF).

Comment: It is a small desktop like app that I want to rework as it is currently a windows form app. Would it make any sense to use silverlight in that instance?

Comment: @chobo: If it's pretty self-contained, and doesn't need deep OS integration, then yes.  SL works great for interacting with online services or simple internal work.

Answer (score 1):

WPF has at its disposal the entire .NET framework while Silverlight in an attempt to be lightweight has a part of the framework (plus some really cool things).  So, it really depends on the scope and deployment methods.  To me it makes more sense to make a Silverlight application a desktop application than to make a WPF application deploy through the web.  But again, let the scope dictate.  If you're wondering which to learn, the answer is simple - either one as they are similar enough that when you're good at one you'll be okay in the other.

Comment: Oh yeah, if you need 3D then your choices are more limited until SL5 - WPF utilizes the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

If you're used to WPF, you'll find that Silverlight lacks a bunch of major and minor features like data triggers, FindAncestor, synchronous WebClient requests, and so on. Probably not deal breakers but definitely annoyances.