# WPF for Silverlight folks

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight

For the last couple of years I have worked with Silverlight (from version 2 to 4) and never seriously used WPF. Are there any quick tours/links/tutorials that explains and introduces WPF: differences to Silverlight and its unique features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible duplicate of [WPF vs Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944608/wpf-vs-silverlight)?

Anyway, it won't be hard, as WPF introduces a greater feature set, and most are MORE extensive than SL. It's a like bit more features built ON TOP of SL, so your existing skills will definitely do. (I did the other way around, from WPF to Silverlight - for some web apps, and I confirm that it is harder)

Comment: Thanks. That question is about two years old and some of the answers are outdated, but it is still a great link!

Answer (score 3):

These links might be helpful -

WPF Compatibility
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925%28VS.95%29.aspx

Writing Cross-Platform XAML Applications
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/09/writing-cross-platform-xaml-applications.aspx

XAML Processing Differences Between Silverlight Versions and WPF
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917841%28VS.95%29.aspx

Porting from WPF to Silverlight: The Missing Pieces, Part 2
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/09/23/porting-from-wpf-to-silverlight-the-missing-pieces-part-2.aspx