# Similarities between WPF and Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I came across differences between WPF and silverlight over the links in the web but I couldn't find any content regarding the similarities in wpf and silverlight. Can anybody please let me know the common points between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This document goes through the differences and the simialarities between the two.  It's 69 pages so a bit of a read, but it should cover what you need.

[WPF/Silverlight White Paper on Codeplex](http://wpfslguidance.codeplex.com/releases/view/28278)

Answer (score 0):

WPF is a more mature technology and was designed with a richer feature set.  It also has the advantage of being able to run in a browser or as an installed Windows-Form-type app.

Silverlight has a broader reach.  You can access Silverlight from many operating systems and web browsers.

The most important reason to choose one over the other should be based on the intended audience for the application.

See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921107(v=pandp.20).aspx) to get more information. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944608/wpf-vs-silverlight) also.