# Need to develop WPF to check new version

Tags: wpf, installation

Once I have developed Wpf application, I have created setup and distributed to users. If I  got some change request, I need to fix that changes and need to give setup again to user. They have to remove older version and reinstall new one.

Is any solution available to avoid removing and reinstalling?

Chand

Comment: Please change tags to `installation` and `update` or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) allows you to create easy to install, self-updating applications.

It's part of the standard Visual Studio tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is not limited to C# or WPF.

You must provide an intelligent installer which might be capable to detect the file versions an/or dates and knows which to replace and which not to touch. Therefore the installer can *install* or *update* depending on the situation.

Also Visual Studio comes with an installer solution I personally prefer [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It makes installation, update and deinstallation an easy task and works with every language.

Answer (score 0):

If [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/) can fulfill your requirements, there is only one install for each client - Silverlight runtime for the browser.
The application will be automatically updated when modified in the web server.

The Silverlight runtime is very similar to WPF, but watch for the differences:
[what-is-the-difference-between-wpf-and-silverlight-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629927/what-is-the-difference-between-wpf-and-silverlight-application).